# Facing errors when reading huge text in python

Tags: python

Using Python3 my requirement is to read email files from a directory and filter Html tags in it.

I have managed to do it to a large extent.When I try to read the content of my output, it gives an error

```
for line in output.splitlines():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'
```

---

```
for file in glob.glob('spam/*.*'):
    output = os.system("python html2txt.py " + file)
    for line in output.splitlines():
     print(line)
```

When I print output, it shows a filtered text.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read the documentation on the return value of `os.system`... Also, why do you need to run `python` OS command from within python? Import the module...

Answer (score 1):

Try this as a replacement for the code you've provided:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('spam/*.*')

for f in files:
    with open(f) as spam_file:
        for line in spam_file:
            print(line)
```

If the files are indeed html files, I would recommend looking into [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `os.system(command)` is system-dependent, it supposes to return the (encoded) process exit value which represented by an `int`. read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
>   meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
>   value of the Python function is system-dependent.
>
> On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell
>   after running command, given by the Windows environment variable
>   COMSPEC: on command.com systems (Windows 95, 98 and ME) this is always
>   0; on cmd.exe systems (Windows NT, 2000 and XP) this is the exit
>   status of the command run; on systems using a non-native shell,
>   consult your shell documentation.

But in no system it returns a `str` and the method `splitlines()` is a str method. read more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_splitlines.htm)

You are calling a `str` method on a `int` that is why you get the error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Answer (score 0):

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
>   meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
>   value of the Python function is system-dependent.
>
> On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell
>   after running command. The shell is given by the Windows environment
>   variable COMSPEC: it is usually cmd.exe, which returns the exit status
>   of the command run; on systems using a non-native shell, consult your
>   shell documentation.
>   [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.system)

So your `output` variable is a integer not the result of the file being parsed by the 
html2txt.py script.

And why do you run another python script outside of your current process ? Can't you just import whatever class of function that is doing the job from that module ?

Also there is an [email module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html) that can help you